# Pass an array from vba to php web service

Tags: php, mysql, excel, vba

Is there anyway I can pass an array constructed in the vba to a php web service??? I have been looking for that with out any success. I do not now if that is possible. So.. what I want to do is: I got a form made in Excel, so I filled it up and then I press a button and stores the data into an dynamic array, an I want to save this in a mysql data base, and I would like to do it by passing the array to a php file to be able to save it in the data base. I will appreciate any help on this! Thanks a lot...

Answer (score 1):

If you need a `PHP` script getting the array data via `HTTP` then the data must be serialized somehow. If you do that the same way a `HTML` `Form` would do it, then you can PHP let work the same way it would work with such `HTML` `Form` data.

Example:

test/test.php:

```
<?php
var_dump($_POST);
?>
```

VBA:

```
Sub XMLHTTP_Post_Request()

 aDataArray = Array("input1=Hello", "input2=World", "idValue=12345")

 sData = Join(aDataArray, "&")
 Debug.Print sData

 Set oWinHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP.6.0")
 oWinHTTP.Open "POST", "http://test/test.php", False

 oWinHTTP.SetRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"

 oWinHTTP.Send sData

 Debug.Print oWinHTTP.ResponseText

End Sub
```

So the `$_POST` array in `PHP` will be:

```
array(3) {
  ["input1"]=>
  string(5) "Hello"
  ["input2"]=>
  string(5) "World"
  ["idValue"]=>
  string(5) "12345"
}
```

Note that this example contains only `ASCII` data. If you have other data, you must `urlencode` the data.